# Dirichlet series of the reciprocal radical function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Define $ rad(n):=\prod_{p|n}p $ and $a_n:=\frac{n}{rad(n)}.$ For example $a_n=1$ whenever n is a squarefree integer. The associated Dirichlet series $$F(s):=\sum_{n} \frac{a_n}{n^s}=\prod_{p} (1+\frac{1}{p^s} \frac{1}{1-p^{1-s}})$$ has abscissa of convergence $s_0=1.$  Are there any results regarding the distribution of $a_n$, e.g. whether $\sum \limits_{n \leq x} a_n \ll x (\log x)^A $ for some  real constant $A>0$  ?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Answer (score 10):

This problem was studied by De Bruijn, see

> N. G. de Bruijn and J. H. van Lint, "On the number of integers $\le x$ whose prime
>   factors divide $n$", Acta Arith. 8 (1963) 349–356

The main result is that $$\log\left(S(x)\right)=\log\left(\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1}{rad(n)}\right)\sim \left(\frac{8\log x}{\log \log x}\right)^{1/2}$$ and that 
$$\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n}{rad(n)}=o\left(xS(x)\right).$$
See also the article ["Idempotents and Nilpotents Modulo n"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0605019) for a discussion of this and similar problems (and more complete references).

Comment: I take it the appearances of $n$ in the last term of the first display should instead be $x$?

Answer (score 4):

A complete answer is at [Asymptotic behavior of a "strange" arithmetic function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445395/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-strange-arithmetic-function). The sum $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n$ is not $O(x (\log x)^A)$ for any $A$, due to the precise asymptotics stated there for the sum.